# Using microsoft speech recognition, could I get the moment when it starts and when it ends?

Tags: speech-recognition

I am playing with the Microsoft engine about the speech recognition. The code is like:

```
static ManualResetEvent _completed = null;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     _completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
     SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
     _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("test")) Name = { "testGrammar" }); // load a grammar
     _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit")) Name = { "exitGrammar" }); // load a "exit" grammar
     _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += _recognizer_SpeechRecognized; 
     _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); // set the input of the speech recognizer to the default audio device
     _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); // recognize speech asynchronous
     _completed.WaitOne(); // wait until speech recognition is completed
     _recognizer.Dispose(); // dispose the speech recognition engine
} 
void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Result.Text == "test") // e.Result.Text contains the recognized text
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The test was successful!");
     } 
     else if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
     {
         _completed.Set();
     }
}
```

It seems to work very cool. And the program could get when I talk like "test" or "exit". But could I get the exact moment when the program starts and when the program finishes testing and restarts to test another word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`RecognitionResult.Audio`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognitionresult.audio(v=vs.110).aspx) has the start time and duration for the audio.

```
void SpeechRecognizedHandler(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Result == null) return;

  // Add event handler code here.

  // The following code illustrates some of the information available
  // in the recognition result.
      Console.WriteLine("Grammar({0}): {1}", e.Result.Grammar.Name, e.Result.Text);
      Console.WriteLine("Audio for result:");
      Console.WriteLine("  Start time: "+ e.Result.Audio.StartTime);
      Console.WriteLine("  Duration: " + e.Result.Audio.Duration);
      Console.WriteLine("  Format: " + e.Result.Audio.Format.EncodingFormat);
}
```

Comment: By the way, could I get the audio and save it in a file.wav?

Comment: @lovemiao Sure, look at [`RecognizedAudio.WriteToWaveStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.recognizedaudio.writetowavestream(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The SpeechRecognitionEngine has a [`SpeechDetected`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.speechdetected(v=vs.110).aspx) Event. You can use this to determine when it identifies the next word to process.

From above link's Remarks section(*emphasis mine*):

> Each speech recognizer **has an algorithm to distinguish between silence and speech**. When the SpeechRecognitionEngine performs a speech recognition operation, **it raises the SpeechDetected event when its algorithm identifies the input as speech**. The AudioPosition property of the associated SpeechDetectedEventArgs object **indicates location in the input stream where the recognizer detected speech**. The SpeechRecognitionEngine raises the SpeechDetected event **before** it raises any of the SpeechHypothesized, SpeechRecognized, or SpeechRecognitionRejected events.

Comment: SpeechDetected occurs before recognition.  It indicates that the engine has processed something that *looks* like speech, although it may not be.

Comment: @Eric True I don't disagree with you. But since OP was wanting time at start, other than waiting for the word to processed this seemed like the next best thing, otherwise you are reacting after the fact.